Can Raspberry Pi 5 hardware decode 4k @ 60 Hz VC1 10 bit video?
Documentation on hardware decoding support is scarce.

No it can't.
The only format it can hardware decode is H.265
This is due to the broadcom BCM58712 only supporting this format for hardware decode. Hardware encoding was dropped entirely
